# Create a push notification icon without AbsoluteLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a icons with texts and also have an unread count on right corner like this one
[image]

I have made this by using AbsoluteLayout, but it is deprecated...

How else it is possible to do this?

Comment: What about making the icon a canvas and drawing the circle and number atop the icon?

Comment: Not a bad idea I'll try. The only problem will be the different resolutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a RelativeLayout as the container of the icon and the unread count number. Add a margin to the top and right of the icon, and set the circled number to `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`.